# Azure web role not able to debug even though symbles loaded

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

I have a cloud service which is having a webrole project.

I have put the break points in Webrole.cs class file and Gloabal.asax class file

When I try to debug the cloud service, only Gloabal.asax file debugger is getting fired. But it never goes to the webrole class file debugger. The debugger symbols are loaded properly.I am able to debug my WCF service but not able to debug Webrole class file.

FYI I set cloud service project as startup project and both cloud and webrole projects running under iisexpress.

Even whatever tracing information I put in the onstart and run methods inside webrole are also not logged.

In WaIISHost.log file I can see the last entry as below.

WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00007080:00000001, 2016/05/16 12:09:56.562, INFO ] Role initialized completely, will wait forever

Could somebody help me to identity the issue. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Just want to update incase any one having same problem as me. I am having Azure SDK  and diagnostic 2.6 version dlls but I am having emulator 2.9 version. This caused the problem. I uninstalled 2.9 emulator version and installed the 2.6 version emulator which matches to my SDK and Diagnostic version dlls. This solved my problem.